# Связь socket и servlet

Tags: java, сокет, servlet

Начал разбираться с сервлетами и задался вопросом:

`Servlet` это не обертка ли для `IO.Socket` для более удобной работы с `web`?

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в идее как оно внутри работает...

Comment: вы знаете про CGI?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman только совсем в общем что это некий протокол по которому происходит передача данных клиент-сервер(только что прочитал)

Comment: servlet - это CGI на java

Comment: [Спеку](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) читали?